# Echo Groups not working with OpenAPI generated code using oapi-codegen

Tags: go, openapi, go-echo

I am using [oapi-codegen](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen) to generate my server code and Echo Labstack as the server.
When I pass a `Group` instance to `Openapi.RegisterHandlers` instead of an `Echo` instance, I always get a 400 error with `{"message":"no matching operation was found"}` for any request in that group:

```
    swagger, err := Openapi.GetSwagger()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error loading swagger spec\n: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Use oapi validation middleware to check all requests against the
    // OpenAPI schema.
    g := e.Group("/api", middleware.OapiRequestValidator(swagger))
    Openapi.RegisterHandlers(g, &MyApi{})
```

If send request `/api/foo`, where `foo` is an API endpoint defined in the generated server code, I get a 400 error. If I do `/api/<some undefined api>` I also get 400. If I do send a request for `/baz`, I get 404 as expected, since that isn't a defined route. If I don't pass a prefix to `Group()`, I get a 400 error for every request. I get the same behavior if I use `RegisterHandlersWithBaseURL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug where if you specify the a base path, either to the `Group()` function or to `RegisterHandlersWithBaseURL()`, the`OapiRequestValidator` middle ignores the base path when checking the request path against the routes. It uses the routes defined in the OpenAPI spec without the base path. To work around this, I overwrote the `inline.tmpl` template and hacked the `GetSwagger()` function to include this at the bottom:

```
func GetSwagger(pathPrefix string) (swagger *openapi3.T, err error) {
...
    var updatedPaths openapi3.Paths = make(openapi3.Paths)

    for key, value := range(swagger.Paths) {
        updatedPaths[pathPrefix + key] = value
    }

    swagger.Paths = updatedPaths
}
```

The key in the `Path` map is the route. I just append the base path to every key.